# Do I need to encrypt the user's info in Firebase Database?

Tags: firebase

So, I'm using a simple, email/password authentication system and I wanted to know if there is a way to encrypt the information that I push there. If not how can I assure the user that their data is encrypted and their privacy is safe? Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you can't encrypt anything in Firebase Database. Google encrypts everything by itself and you don't need to care about hacker attacks. The only things you need to care about are the security rules and keeping your program, not too server or mobile dependent.

If you do want to assure your users that their information is completely private and only known to them, then you can manually encrypt the information. There are many encryption algorithms, but I would recommend the [AES Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Encryption_Standard), as it is fast and efficient. The encryption key can be stored locally on your device without having to transfer it to the server, ensuring the user's privacy.

Comment: Oh thanks for the answer, it was exactly what I wanted!

Comment: Your welcome buddy, just highlight the grey tick if it helped you.